# Lazy View pager for a bunch of items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-view

I need to have view pager for swiping between products (Fragments), when I click on any product from the list, I can swipe left or right for navigation to adjacent product.  Is there any efficient way to do this, not to load extra info into the memory.

Comment: I would look in to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: please,add more description what you want exactly so that you get desired answer of your question...